# VBA: Deleting an excel row based on first occurrence of a value in a column

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best way using VBA to find the first occurrence of a specific value in column A and delete that entire row? Example:

- **A**
- A
- **B**
- B
- B
- **C**
- C
- C
- C

I need to find each of the bold letters and delete all the data in their row. This column will always have repeats as the report that exports this data sets the first row of each group (A,B, or C) as the total row.

Comment: Use `Application.Match`.

Comment: You can also loop through the column. Because you're deleting, it is more natural to loop backwards and find the "last" occurance of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VBA, you can go down the column and search for values that don't match the previous row.

```
Sub DropTotals()
   Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' sheet with data
   col = 1  ' data column to check
   rw = 2  ' data start row
   For ctr = 1 To 9999  ' prevent endless loop
      If ws.Cells(rw, col) = "" Then: Exit For  ' end of data
      If ws.Cells(rw, col).Value <> ws.Cells(rw - 1, col).Value Then ' if does not match previous row
          Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete  ' delete row
      End If
      rw = rw + 1  ' next row
   Next
End Sub
```

Before:                           After:

[image: ExcelBeforeAfter]

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. I was blanking on how to compare two rows. I have been using a CountIf method and deleting the first occurrence, this runs much faster.